# Unable to send websocket data from flutter app to go server

Tags: go, flutter, websocket

I am trying to create a server-client architecture using flutter app client and go server.
Currently I am trying to send text input from flutter app, to read and print it on the server side using Websockets.

I have successfully tested my flutter app to echo from https://www.websocket.org/echo.
To connect to my local server,here is the relevant bit

For connecting to server

```
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://localhost:8080/test');
```

When onPressed,to send user entered data, sendMessage() is called;

```
void sendMessage(){
    if(myController.text.isNotEmpty){
      channel.sink.add(myController.text);
    }
  }
```

I have read the https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket docs and other blogs to understand mux, handlefunc and listenandserve functions, but I'm not able to send data.

Here is my Go server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize: 1024,
    }

func connectionHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w,r,nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for{
            messageType, p, err := conn.NextReader()
            fmt.Println(p)
            fmt.Println(messageType)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
    }

}

func main(){

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    fmt.Printf("Connecting to server \n")

    mux.HandleFunc("/test", connectionHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux))

}
```

Edit:
Added Flutter Client code.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/html.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/status.dart' as status;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Shopping',
      initialRoute: 'home',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        'home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(title: "Home"),
        '/shoppingpage': (BuildContext context) => ShoppingCart(title: "Shopping Cart Page"),
      },

    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key:key);
  final String title;
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://localhost:8080/test');
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void dispose(){
    myController.dispose();
    channel.sink.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                return (Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/shoppingpage'));
              },
              child: Text('Start Game'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              splashColor: Colors.green,

          ),

          TextField(
            controller: myController,

          ),

          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){
              sendMessage();
              _scaffoldkey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Sent'),
              ));
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.send),
          ),

          StreamBuilder(
            stream: channel.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              return snapshot.hasData ? Text(snapshot.data.toString(),
              ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendMessage(){
    if(myController.text.isNotEmpty){
      channel.sink.add(myController.text);
    }
  }

}



class ShoppingCart extends StatelessWidget {
  ShoppingCart({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(onPressed: (){
          return Navigator.pop(context);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide more detail on what happens when a message is sent; Is the handler in the Go code called?  Does the handler log any errors?

Comment: That's the entire code for my server, no the handler doesn't log any error. But I printed statement inside the handler code and according to it, code never went inside the handler.

Comment: The Go program will print messages sent to the endpoint at ws://localhost:8080/test. Suggested first step in debugging the problem: Go to http://localhost:8080/test in a web browser.  You should get 400 response with message about a bad ws handshake. If you don't get this message, then there's some sort of operational error with the server (the server not running is an example of an operational error).  If you do get the message, then look for problems in the client application.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Checked localhost;8080/test on my browser and got bad request as you mentioned. I have double checked my client code but still can't figure anything wrong. So updated my post with client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running the Go server on your PC but the Flutter app on a mobile/emulator, then `localhost` won't work (it'll point back to the mobile/emulator, not the PC).

You'll need to use an IP address/hostname that resolves to the PC from the phone and ensure the Go server is bound to the network-accessible IP (and that there's no firewall in the way).

Comment: Thanks for this, I changed my flutter app's ip to local ip of my pc (found this using ifconfig). Also I had to change my server ip to 0.0.0.0 from localhost so that all local ip can listen to the server. This answer explained it well [link] (https://superuser.com/a/949522)

Answer (score 0):

More detailed answer:

---

on linux you can get the IP address with:

`hostname -I` or `ifconfig`

(the one after "inet:")

---

and then in Flutter:

```
static String serverIP = "192.168.0.3"; // your IP instead of localhost
static String port = "8080";
final WebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://$serverIP:$port");
```

Huge thanks to OP and @Danny Tuppeny for the explanations as to why